# How to get the 95th and 5th percentiles separately?

Tags: r

I have data (e.g.d and di) that I want to do some calculations.

data:

```
d= 1:20
xi= 2:21
```

I would like to use this equation(using the 95th and 5th percentiles separately for both d and xi):

```
          res= d(95th)-d(5th)/xi(95th)+xi(5th)
          res2= res + xi(5th)
```

we get 95th and 5th percentiles using this function(provided by users of stackoverflow):

```
   fun <- function(x){
quantiles <- quantile( x, c(.05, .95 ) )
x[ x < quantiles[1] ] <- quantiles[1]
x[ x > quantiles[2] ] <- quantiles[2]
x
                  }
```

but this does not apply to my case as I want to use the 95th and 5th percentiles separately in the equation above.any ideas please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
your_fun <- function(x,y){
    qx <- quantile(x,c(.05,.95))
    qy <- quantile(y,c(.05,.95))
    out <- diff(qx)/diff(qy)
    out2 <- out + qy[1]

    names(out) <- NULL
    names(out2) <- NULL
    list(res=out,res2=out2)
}

your_fun(d,xi)
```

which gives

```
$res
[1] 1

$res2
[1] 3.95
```

Comment: Many thanks Frank.is there a way to get only the 95th or 5th percentiles? Please  look at my equation again

Comment: @ZadSim Okay, I've edited my question to return both `res` and `res2`, in a list. Sorry if I have misunderstood. You can return just `res2` by putting it on the last line of the function. I think you may soon want to read more about the basics of R. There's a good list of resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info